# Запретить отображение DialogFragment при разблокировке экрана

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть кастомный DialogFragment, вызывающийся из другого фрагмента:

```
final CustomCalendarDialogFragment newFragment = new CustomCalendarDialogFragment("CHOOSE_WEEK");
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (newFragment.isAdded()){
                //если фрагмент был создан - показать
                newFragment.getDialog().show();
            } else {
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "CUSTOM_CALENDAR");
            }
        }
    });
```

В CustomCalendarDialogFragment при нажатии на кнопку "ОК":

`getDialog().hide();`

После нажатия на кнопку "ОК" фрагмент скрывается, но при разблокировке экрана снова отображается, как это устранить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо скрытия диалога закрывать его:

```
getDialog().dismiss();
```

Comment: мне нужно именно скрыть а не закрыть

Comment: @parovoz, а в чём принципиальное отличие в вашем случае?

Comment: при dismiss() теряется вся информация которую пользователь задал в фрагменте(в моем случае дата). dismiss() у меня висит на кнопке "Cancel". А по кнопке "ОК" просто hide()

Comment: @parovoz, просто сохраните полученное значение куда-нить, в SharedPreferences, например и закрывайте диалог.